# Cant upload Image with Reactjs Nodejs MongoDb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, post, multer

I'm trying to upload a image using React for my client side, Node Js as my server and monogoDb for my database. I'm using multer to store the images and everytime I make a request to create an account I get a 500 error. How do I make a post request that includes a Image to a monogoDb database from my React frontend through a Node Js server ?

Frontend

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import FormData from 'form-data'
import axios from "axios";

const CreateAccount = () => {
  const api = "http://localhost:5000/user/create-account";

  const history = useHistory();

  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [emailAddress, setEmailAddress] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [gender, setGender] = useState("Male");
  const [sexualPreference, setSexualPreference] = useState("Straight");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [picture, setPicture] = useState(null);
  const [imgData, setImgData] = useState(null);

  const account = {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    emailAddress: emailAddress,
    password: password,
    gender: gender,
    sexualPreference: sexualPreference,
    age: age,
    description: description,
    pictures: picture
  };

  const onChangePicture = e => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      console.log("picture: ", e.target.files);
      setPicture(e.target.files[0]);
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        setImgData(reader.result);
      });
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
    console.log(imgData);
    console.log(picture);
  };
  

  const submit = () => {

    let data = new FormData(); 

    data.append('firstName', firstName);
    data.append('lastName', lastName);
    data.append('emailAddress', emailAddress);
    data.append('password', password);
    data.append('gender', gender);
    data.append('sexualPreference',sexualPreference);
    data.append('age', age);
    data.append('description', description);
    data.append('pictures',
    {
       uri: imgData,
       name:`${picture}.jpg`,
       type:'image/jpg'
    });

    axios.post(api, account, {
      method: "post",
      url: api,
      data: account,
     headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
     })
     .then((res) => {
      // handle success
      console.log(res.data);
      history.push({
        pathname: "/",
      });
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       //handle error
       console.log(account);
       console.log(error);
      });
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    submit();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Create account</h1>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
        <p>First Name</p>
        <input
          id="firstName"
          name="firstName"
          type="firstName"
          onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <p>Last Name</p>
        <input
          id="lastName"
          name="lastName"
          type="lastName"
          onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <p>Email Address</p>
        <input
          id="emailAddress"
          name="emailAddress"
          type="emailAddress"
          onChange={(e) => setEmailAddress(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <p>Password</p>
        <input
          id="password"
          name="password"
          type="password"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <p>Gender</p>
        <select
          id="gender"
          name="gender"
          type="gender"
          onChange={(e) => setGender(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option value="Male">Male</option>
          <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
        <p>Sexual Preference</p>
        <select
          id="sexualPreference"
          name="sexualPreference"
          type="sexualPreference"
          onChange={(e) => setSexualPreference(e.target.value)}
        >
          <option value="Straight" >Straight</option>
          <option value="Gay" >Gay</option>
          <option value="Lesbian" >Lesbian</option>
          <option value="Bisexual" >Bisexual</option>
        </select>
        <p>Age</p>
        <input
          id="age"
          name="age"
          type="age"
          onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <p>Description</p>
        <input
          id="description"
          name="description"
          type="description"
          onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
        <input 
          type="file" 
          name="file"  
          id="picture" 
          onChange={onChangePicture}
          ></input>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateAccount;
```

Backend

```
const multer = require("multer");


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
  }
})

const upload = multer({storage: storage})

router.post( "/user/create-account", upload.single("pictures"), [
    check("firstName")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "firstName"'),
    check("lastName")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "username"'),
    check("emailAddress")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "emailAddress"'),
    check("password")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "password"'),
    check("gender")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "gender"'),
    check("sexualPreference")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "sexualPreference"'),
    check("age")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "age"'),
    check("description")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "description"'),
    check("pictures")
      .exists({ checkNull: true, checkFalsy: true })
      .withMessage('Please provide a value for "pictures"'),
  ],
  asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    // Attempt to get the validation result from the Request object.
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    // If there are validation errors...
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      // Use the Array `map()` method to get a list of error messages.
      const errorMessages = errors.array().map((error) => error.msg);

      // Return the validation errors to the client.
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errorMessages });
    }

    //new user request body using mongo model from schema
    const postUser = new User({
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      emailAddress: req.body.emailAddress,
      password: req.body.password,
      gender: req.body.gender,
      sexualPreference: req.body.sexualPreference,
      age: req.body.age,
      description: req.body.description,
      pictures: req.file.path
    });
    console.log(req.file)
    const userEmail = await User.findOne({
      emailAddress: postUser.emailAddress,
    });

    if (postUser.emailAddress === userEmail) {
      console.log("User with this email already exists");

      return res.status(500).end();
    } else if (postUser) {
      //if true salts the password with bcryptjs
      let salt = await bcryptjs.genSalt(10);
      const hashPass = await bcryptjs.hash(postUser.password, salt);
      console.log(hashPass);
      postUser.password = hashPass;
      postUser.save();

      res.json({ postUser });
      return res.status(201).end();
    } else {
      res.status(400).send({ error: "Error: Account not created" }).end();
    }
  })
);
```

schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema( {

    firstName:{
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    emailAddress: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
   gender:{
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    sexualPreference: {
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true 
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    pictures: {
    
        type: String,
        required: true 
    },
    matches: {
        type: [{
            Object
        }],
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: You're creating a form with FormData but you're not sending it with axios. Does the 500 error say anything more?

Comment: axios.post('url', data) may work; u can access them in backend as req.body.object_key and u can access photos as req.file

Comment: u can also check my github repo. I have done the same thing but in simpler way. https://github.com/RUPAAK/RENTAL_PROJECT/blob/master/client/src/screens/SellRoom.js#L21

Comment: @MaximOrlov unfortanly is does not. Thank you for pointing that out for me tho!

Comment: @Rupak I will have a look now, cheers mate!